# SQLite group_concat nextline

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

i am using sqlite manager in firefox and the sqlite file will be connected to netbeans GUI.

I want the separator to be a newline.
For example:

```
table1 | table2
1      | a
1      | b
1      | c
2      | d
2      | e
```

And i want the output to be:

```
table1 | table2
1      | a
       | b
       | c
2      | d
       | e
```

I used this code but i don't know the separator for newline/nextline

```
select  table1, group_concat(table2) from Table group by table1
```

This return:

```
table1 | table2
1      | abc
2      | de
```

i forgot this is my code in netbeans:

```
String sql = "select  DateAdded, group_concat(Word) from RFID group by DateAdded";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            x.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the OS, a newline is a control character with value 13 (OS X), or 10 (Unix), or both characters (Windows):

```sql
SELECT table1,
       group_concat(table2, char(13) || char(10))
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY table1;
```

Comment: the output is still the same gives me "abc".

Comment: i tried it on netbeans, but got an error "SQLException: no such function: char"

Comment: Then it has an older version of the SQLite library.